# github issue comment received via email won't render code block

Tags: github, markdown

I have a GitHub issue comment [here](https://github.com/gordonj7/publictest/issues/1) (the third comment down) that I'd like to edit so that it looks prettier, by rendering part of it as a code block.

But it doesn't work; the three backticks show up as literal text.

Anyone know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GitHub treats comments received via email differently from comments entered in the web UI. If you look at your comments you'll see that the third one displays an envelope icon beside your name with mouseover text saying, "This comment left via email reply."

In [a blog post](https://github.com/blog/811-reply-to-comments-from-email), GitHub suggests that Markdown formatting is not permitted in email replies:

> We figured out early on in testing that we couldn't expect people to write Markdown. People are going to be dumping code or stacktraces, and will expect them to look nicely.

And later, gives this caveat:

> Plain text email is vastly preferred. Essentially, we strip all HTML from HTML emails before formatting.

I can't find a better description of how formatting of emailed issue comments is handled, but I don't think you're going to be able to use Markdown if you reply by email.